# Task Bar at the top missing Applications, Places and System menu

Tags: unity, gnome, .desktop, hud

I was trying to install VLC using System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager when I realised that I don't have Applications, Places and System menu items at the top left side of task bar.

I am new to Ubuntu but I intend to use it as a developer. I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 which is GNOME, as I checked using this command:

```
ls /usr/bin/*session*
```

which is not a menu item at the top left side of task bar. Can I add them? I will need them from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mate Desktop Environment. This is a fork of the classic GNOME 2.0 Desktop Environment. So you'll get the Applications, Places & System.

More info :

http://mate-desktop.org/

Installation Guide :

http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download